# following javascript code turns reason value false

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the following code turns reason value false?

```
if (reason = "" || reason == null) {
  return;
}
alert(reason);
```

Comment: `reason = ""` this is assignment. You probably want comparison `reason === ""`

Comment: because you are assigning `reason = ""` which coerces to a falsy value

Comment: It doesn't. It turns it into an empty string, as you instruct it: `reason = ""`. If you want a comparison, write `reason == ""` or better yet `reason === ""`.

Comment: The code you posted would be probably throwing errors in your console

Comment: edit it properly i can guess you want to check it not want to assign to it

Comment: @Anonymoose: This is incorrect. The value of the assignment is the value being assigned; in this case, an empty string (which is falsy, not true). An assignment can either be successful, or throw an exception; its return value is not related to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reason` will be `false` (in most cases) after that code snippet because the **assignment** operator used:

```
reason = ...
       ^
       └── assignment
```

has a lower **precedence** than `||` and `==`. Thus the expression:

```
"" || reason == null
```

will be evaluated first, being `false` for any value of `reason` other than `null` or `undefined`, and then assigned back to `reason`.

If the whole thing evaluates to `false`, the inner return never executes.

---

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

---

```js
const test = (reason) => "" || reason == null;

console.log( test("something") );
console.log( test("") );
console.log( test(null) );
console.log( test(false) );
console.log( test(0) );
console.log( test(undefined) );
```

---

The above is the answer to the *"why-question"*. But as the assignment operator is probably a simple typo, to make the code more sensible, you'd simply need to use two comparisons (using strict comparison `===` to prevent accidental type coercion), e.g.:

```
if (reason === "" || reason === null) { // ...
```

Comment: This explanation is exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

with `reason = ""` you are assigning a value to the reason variable, use the conditional operator `reason == ""`